# Is there necessarily an in-kernel copy in Linux zero-copy networking?

Tags: linux, networking, io

I see some Linux zero-copy networking example illustrations on the internet like the following ones:

The usual IO example:

[image: 1]

Zero copy IO example:

[image: 2]

I see it eliminates CPU copies; it also eliminates usual in-kernel buffer copies.

What I'm interested in is, when I'm e.g. receiving network data and mmap-ing it to userspace, is there an in-kernel copy involved? A copy from a 'NIC buffer' to a 'socket buffer'; or can these two be the same thing?

As I understand, on higher-end NICs the 'NIC buffer' might be located in the NIC's own memory; so would my hypothetical attempt try to mmap NIC's memory? (Is it possible?)

Basically I'm interested in what the 'DMA copy' means for the NICs - can it mean copying from 'the wire' into the kernel buffer that can be mmap-ed (and vice versa), or does it necessarily mean there's a copy between some intermediate NIC buffer (which gets populated from 'the wire') and the kernel buffer that can be used by the userspace.

In any case, can I get the data directly to userspace, bypassing the 'socket buffer'? I guess smth analogous to O_DIRECT with disk IO. (I'm not talking about a complete kernel-bypass.)

I'd like to know how it works on my usual x86-64 Linux box, and how can it work on same current higher-end architecture.